# Arduino Serial Writing Array Problem

Tags: serial, communication, array

I am trying to communicate Pc - Arduino Uno.

My Arduino code is here: (It is working as below)

```
int ndx = 0;
char pack[12];            
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial){;}
}

  void loop() { 

   while(Serial.available() ){  
    char rb = Serial.read();
    pack[ndx] = rb;
    ndx++;
    Serial.write(rb);
    if(ndx == 12){ 
        ndx=0;
      }     
    }
    }
```

If I try in

```
Serial.write(rb);
```

Like that:

```
Serial.write(pack[ndx]);
```

Program is acting weird, I mean sending weird bytes. I do not know what is the reason. Can you help me, please? What is going on in code?
My python code:
https://github.com/mucahitkayadan/Python

Comment: A character is send as a ascii character, not the decimal value. Try to cast it to an int or try using DEC as second parameter. With such a low baudrate, should it be better to add a seperator? for example a comma between the values.

Comment: we do not see the definition of the array

Comment: @Juraj Sorry, There were some unnecessary definions. When I was posting,I deleted them, and array definion was out of sight. I fixed,edited it.

Comment: @Jot I can add comma in between every values in python list, but will it be easier? I have not understood the algorithm you are talking about.

Comment: Post the code that is not working

Comment: @Juraj What is the error? Working on me. It needs serial connection and I have. If you don't have, maybe thats why. I am not sure but it is working on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you replace `Serial.write(rb);` to `Serial.write(pack[ndx]);` and get?:

```
char rb = Serial.read();
pack[ndx] = rb;
ndx++;
Serial.write(pack[ndx]);
```

then you read an uninitialized array item on the next index

Comment: Actually, it is working without using array. I you use directly " Serial.write(inByte); " it is working normally.
But if you use " Serial.write(array[index]); " it is working weird. Sending 0-255 random numbers or maybe not random but I do not know reason or meaning of that weird numbers.

Comment: I changed the aswer

Comment: I have to process the data, so I need to process with array, namely 'pack[index]', thats why I don't want use Serial.write(rb); When I put "Serial.write(pack[ndx]);" program giving me different weird numbers.

Comment: do you have ndx++ before write(pack[ndx]);?

Comment: Yes, absolutely for this reason. Now it is working. So basic thing I can not believe myself, overlooked.

Comment: And, can I send data under for loop? Like that:
`for(int i = 0 ; i < 12; i++){
Serial.write(pack[i]);
}`

Comment: yes you can do it in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

The sequence:

```
pack[ndx] = rb;
ndx++;
Serial.write(rb);
```

modifies ndx before printing. So in your first case - printing 'rb' - you'll print the value you just stored in the array; in the second case printing 'pack[ndx]' - you'll print whatever happens to be in the *following* member of the array. Swapping the second and third statements in my excerpt will fix it.

Comment: My packs have 12 bytes and I have totally 7 pack.I tried to just send my index, namely 'ndx'. And it receives correctly. I mean, pc receives 0-11 numbers for every time for every pack. It is expected. That thing is what I could not understand, for every iteration rb and pack[rdx] are equal. Why write(rb) is working correctly but write(pack[ndx]) does not work?